# Calculating Jaccard Similarity for a column with python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to take rows which have a jaccard similarity score equal or bigger than %80 accuracy.
I have an excel file like this with thousands of rows:

| id | letters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B,G |
| 2 | B,G |
| 21 | C,D |
| 14 | A,B,C,D |
| 46 | F,E,G,J |
| 35 | X,D,F,A,K |
| 3 | X,D,F,K,A |
| 5 | G,E,F,K,J |
| 56 | G,F,E,J,K |

For example jaccard similarity score between first two rows is: (B,G)/(A,B,G)=2/3=0.66 between 1 and 3: 0 and so on.
I just want to take rows that have equal or bigger than %80  similarity. For example id with 35 has %80 similarity with id 3, id with 5 has %100 similarity with id 56 and %80 similarity with id 46 so output file should be like this:

| id | letters | sub-id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35 | X,D,F,A,K | 35, 3 |
| 5 | G,E,F,K,J | 5, 56, 46 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I currently have.

```
data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 21, 14, 46, 35, 3, 5, 56],
    'letters': ['A,B,G', 'B,G', 'C,D', 'A,B,C,D', 'F,E,G,J', 'X,D,F,A,K', 'X,D,F,K,A', 'G,E,F,K,J', 'G,F,E,J,K']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
    union = (len(list1) + len(list2)) - intersection
    return float(intersection / union)


new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'letters', 'sub-id'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    similarity = []
    # save all the similarity scores in a list
    for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        similarity.append(jaccard_similarity(row['letters'].split(','), row2['letters'].split(',')))
    # find the indexes of the rows that have similarity score bigger than 0.8
    indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(similarity) if x >= 0.8]
    # if there is more than one row with similarity score bigger than 0.8
    if len(indexes) > 1:
        # add the row to the new data frame
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, pd.DataFrame(
            [[row['id'], row['letters'], ','.join([str(df.iloc[i]['id']) for i in indexes])]],
            columns=['id', 'letters', 'sub-id'])], ignore_index=True)

# order the rows by id
new_df = new_df.sort_values(by=['id'])

# order by sub-id size
new_df = new_df.sort_values(by=['sub-id'], key=lambda x: x.str.len(), ascending=True)

# make sure there is only one row for each id
new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['sub-id'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
  id    letters   sub-id
2  3  X,D,F,K,A     35,3
3  5  G,E,F,K,J  46,5,56
```

Now my output is slightly different to yours, which I am still trying to figure out!

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, here the idea is to check each row value similarity score on whole df using nested loop.

To check similarity I've used **fussy** package.

i.e,

```
fuzz.token_sort_ratio('G,E,F,K,J', 'F,E,G,J')    #Out 88

fuzz.token_sort_ratio('A,B,C,D', 'C,D')          #Out 60

fuzz.token_sort_ratio('B,G','A,B,G')             #Out 75
```

Code:

```
from thefuzz import fuzz
data = []

for I in range(len(df)):
    new = df[df.apply(lambda x: [True if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(df['letters'][I], df['letters'][i]) >= 80 else False for i in range(len(df))])].dropna()
    sub_id = new['ID'].tolist()
    row = [int(sub_id[0]), max(new['letters'].tolist()), ','.join(str(int(x)) for x in sub_id)]
    
    if len(new) > 1 and row not in data:
        data.append(row)
        
        
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'Latters', 'Sub-id'])
```

Output:

```
    ID  Latters     Sub-id
0   46  G,E,F,K,J   46,5,56
1   35  X,D,F,A,K   35,3
```

**Another Possible way**:

To change the letter column first, then just apply group by

Code:

```
import itertools
letters = [[df['letters'][i] for i,x in enumerate([fuzz.token_sort_ratio(I,i) >= 80 for i in list(df['letters'])]) if x] for I in df['letters'].tolist()]
letters.sort()
letters = list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(letters))

df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype("string")
df['letters'] = df['letters'].apply(lambda x: max(list(filter(lambda item: item,[l if x in l else None for l in letters]))[0]))
df[df.duplicated(['letters'], keep=False)].groupby('letters')['ID'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Ouput:

```
    letters     ID
0   G,E,F,K,J   46,5,56
1   X,D,F,A,K   35,3
```

**Note** : `Install python-Levenshtein` to avoid fuzz warning